# how to keep newline(s) when selecting a given column with awk

Tags: awk

Suppose I have a file like this (disclaimer: this is not fixed I can have more than 7 rows, and more than 4 columns)

```
R H A 23
S E A 45
T E A 34
U   A 35
Y T A 35
O E A 353
J G B 23
```

I want the output to select second column if third column is A but keeping newline or whitespace character.

output should be:

```
HEE TE
```

I tried this:

```
awk '{if ($3=="A") print $2}' file | awk 'BEGIN{ORS = ""}{print $1}'
```

But this gives:

```
HEETE%
```

Which has a weird `%` and is missing the space.

Comment: If there's a weird `%` in your output then there's a weird `%` in your input - awk doesn't create characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `gnu-awk` solution using `FIELDWIDTHS`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS = "1 1 1 1 1 1 *" } $5 == "A" {s = s $3}
END {print s}' file

HEE TE
```

awk splits each record using width values provided in this variable `FIELDWIDTHS`.

`1 1 1 1 1 1 *` means each of first 6 columns will have single character length and remaining text will be filled in 7th column. Since you have a space after each value so `$2,$4,$6` will be filled with a single space and `$1,$3,$5` will be filled with the provided values in input.

`$5 == "A" {s = s $3}`: Here we are checking if `$5` is `A` and if that condition is true then we keep appending value of `$3` in a variable `s`. In the `END` block we just print variable `s`.

Without using fixed width parsing, `awk` will treat `A` in 4th row as `$2`.

---

Or else if we let spaces part of column value then use:

```sh
awk '
   BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS = "2 2 2 *" }
   $3 == "A " {s = s substr($2,1,1)}
   END {print s}
' file
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have said the file has no fixed length (I don't only have 7 records), would this still work?

Comment: Number of records should not matter. Fixed with pertains to position of individual cell values as shown in your question. File can have thousands of records.

Comment: Ok thanks, could you explain me a bit what this is doing?

Comment: In specific what's the purpose of FIELDWIDTHS and why do we put an s before $3 here: s = s $3? I'm still not very comfortable with awk syntax, so it would be very helpful.

Comment: I have provided some details. My explanation can never be as good as an awk tutorial though.

Comment: sorry I realized my version of awk was not GNU, I gave you the mark again. It did work!